# How to return/break from lambda which is a property?

Tags: kotlin, lambda

How to return/break from lambda which is a property?

```
class Example {

  val handler: ()->String = {
    if (...) {
      return "break"
    }
    "return"
  }
}
```

Note `return@handler` doesn't work.

====================

**Solved**:

```
class Example {

  val handler: ()->String = label@{
    if (...) {
      return@label "break"
    }
    "return"
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you aware that you can label lambdas e.g. `val handler: ()->String = myLabel@{ ... }`, and then use that label in a return statement, e.g. `return@myLabel "break"`? In any case, you don't need to use `return`s most of the time. Why not just `if (...) { "break" } else { "return" }`?

Comment: @Sweeper wow you are right!